# List Snapshot ID's with time under specific VPC ID using PowerShell

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-vpc, aws-powershell

I'm trying to List Snapshot ID's with time under specific VPC ID using PowerShell or AWS CLI

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working. Please visit [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Snapshots are region specific, not VPC specific, therefore you can't directly list all snapshots for a specific VPC.

If you need that kind of filtering, then you can tag each snapshot with a VPC it "belongs" to (i.e `VPCID:value-of-VPC-id`). And then use this command.

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner-ids <your-account-id> --filters Name=tag:VPCID,Values=<value-of-VPC-id>
```

If you want to retrieve only VPC ID and time, then you can enhance the above with `query` parameter

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner-ids <your-account-id> --filters Name=tag:VPCID,Values=<value-of-VPC-id> --query "Snapshots[*].{ID:SnapshotId,Time:StartTime}"
```

Comment: @NarasimhaThejaRao Hey, could you ask that as a followup question so it could be answered separately? That will give the answerer more room to work with than this small comment UI. Thanks!